# TripleDES Key - Generate String Key

Tags: c#, security, encryption, 3des, tripledes

I received the tripleDES key as follow:

2 components of 16 bytes HEX string each.

**Component 1**: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

**KCV 1**: 0000000000000000

**Component 2**: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

**KCV 2**: 0000000000000000

I need to store the final key as UTF8 string in web.config (Development Stage), there is an implementation running in production using this approach, key length is 24 characters, where I only retrieve the key in web.config as follow:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secreteKeyValue);
//Secret key from web.config
```

How can i generate the final key from those components as UTF 8 string to store in web.config and use in the method below ?

```
public static byte[] TripleDes(byte[] inputBuffer, byte[] key)
    {
        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            des.Key = key;
            des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            byte[] result;

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
                cryptoStream.Flush();
                result = stream.ToArray();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I hope you realize that 3DES should not be used in new work, the successor to DES is AES (advanced EncryptionStandard), use it. 3DES has weaknesses including the full triple key (168-bits) only have security of 112-bits. Consider the security of your users.

Comment: I Have no option, 3DES is the standard imposed by the client that I'm integrating, i have only the keys componentes.

Comment: Get a better client. Really, have you made them aware of the security issues? Personally I would just tell them "no" to 3DES.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say no to a client but i would, however, get it in writing that you advised them to not use a encryption method with known weaknesses and that you are not liable for potential security risk that it entails.

Comment: Note that when there is no padding the input data must be an exact multiple of the block size, (8-bytes). Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 Understood and as a last resort that is a good idea. In my experience every time I stood up for security there was a backlash, sometimes to the VP leve,l the end result was a more secure system, more respect and even a better better relationship with the person I stood up to. YMMV.

Comment: @zaph Agreed, not saying abandon the quest to make things right but if no means no gotta protect yourself in the end.

Comment: Yes, we are aware of all security-related risks, unfortunately there is already a solution running in parallel using TripleDES, which is standard for communications between TEF systems.

Comment: Well we would like to migrate to AES, but the customer is aware of the risks and is not able to make these changes.

Comment: Sure, sometimes you need to give in to legacy systems.

Comment: Someone knows how to generate the UTF8 key from those components ?

Comment: The security of 3DES isn't the only issue - it's also significantly slower than AES (because 3DES involves applying the algorithm 3 times, whereas if you're using AES you only have to apply the algorithm once). Incidentally, you can't just store keys in plaintext on the server - you have to take precautions in case someone gains access to your server somehow.

Comment: Ok, All these issues are known, but at the moment i only need to store the key to make some tests on staging with a "Development Key", in production we will use a HSM.